Laravel: Can't run composer install fully with spark-stripe
I cloned a project recently on laravel 10.44 and i wanted to run composer install to make sure i have every installation. But upon coming to laravel/spark-stripe i was asked for authentication. I checked every other question regarding spark-stripe on stackoverflow.
I get the following error:
Failed to execute git clone --mirror -- https://ghp...Fd8:x-oauth-basic@github.com/laravel/spark-stripe.git AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-github.com-laravel-s   
  park-stripe.git/                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Cloning into bare repository 'AppData/Local/Composer/vcs/git-github.com-laravel-spark-stripe.git'...                                                              
  remote: Repository not found.                                                                                                                                                     
  fatal: repository 'https://github.com/laravel/spark-stripe.git/' not found   

And yes i have set up a auth.json file for the authentication of spark.
Here is a more detailed error:
                                                                                                                                                                                    
******************************************************************                                                                                                                  
You do not have a valid license to download this release (v4.3.1)!                                                                                                                  
******************************************************************                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Failed to download laravel/spark-stripe from dist: The "https://spark.laravel.com/dist/laravel/spark-stripe/laravel-spark-stripe-6502033e85f96852f450fd2861daaa6cd04aa598-zip-c53fe0.zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 422 ):                                                                                                                               
{"warning":"\n\n******************************************************************\nYou do not have a valid license to download this release (v4.3.1)!\n************************************************...                                                                                                                                                             
    Now trying to download from source


Can't run an php artisan command either now because of an autoload.php and app.php error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in PhpstormProjects\management\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Error: Class "Illuminate\Foundation\Application" not found in PhpstormProjects\management\bootstrap\app.php on line 14

Call Stack:
    0.0004     395600   1. {main}() PhpstormProjects\management\artisan:0
    0.0047     501224   2. require_once('PhpstormProjects\management\bootstrap\app.php') PhpstormProjects\management\artisan:20   

I have tried every solution i know of and it didn't work. so if someone with more knowledge could help me i would appreciate that.
I tried various solutions like
Reset GitHub login when using composer install
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/spark/cannot-update-or-install-spark
and manually filling in the auth for spark doesn't work since i can't type in the password when asked in the terminal

Why can't you type in the password in Terminal?
